# Gitlab wiki duplicate page error while saving a page

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-wiki

I'm creating a wiki in GitLab but, once i added the homepage at the root of my wiki, i'm getting this error everytime i try to save the pages:

> The form contains the following error:
>
> - Duplicate page: A page with that title already exists

It even says that it couldn't update the wiki page, but if i click cancel i still se the change i made in the page.
I can't understand if i'm doing something wrong or GitLab is giving me a non-existent issue
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX2J2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone searching for a solution, i've found that, to solve the issue,you can leave all the pages free (without writing the page path in the title) and manage the sidebar manually.